# pattern search with special chars

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Hi I want to search and get the index all special chars within a complex string like this

```
String textWithSpecialChars = "text here |*more*| text some other |@tags@|...";
```

Im trying to search all patterns like this `|* |_ |= |@` and `*| _| =| @|` I try this patterns

```
public int getIndexOfPat(String s){
    Pattern startPat = Pattern.compile("\\|[\\*_@=]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}

String textWithSpecialChars = "text here |*more*| text some other |@tags@|...";
int i = getIndexOfPat(textWithSpecialChars);
textWithSpecialChars = textWithSpecialChars.substring(i+2);
//I get error here
i = getIndexOfPat(textWithSpecialChars);
// var i still is the first one value
```

but this only get the first one even if I delete it of the original string with the

Comment: Can searched part contain inner `|` (like `|*foo|bar*|`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that each time you call `getIndexOfPat` you are recreating `Matcher` instance (and Pattern but recompiling Pattern is not problem here, it is just ineffective code). Because of that each time you call `find` it tries to find match from beginning.

You have few options how to solve this problem.

1. let method return list of all founded matches
2. pass method instance of Matcher so you could call `find` on Matcher which remembers where was last match and would search after it.

I would chose option 1 since option 2 would be just wrapping `find` method and returning its result which feels kind of too simple code to be separate method like

```
int getNextIndex(Matcher m){
    return matcher.find() ? matcher.start() : -1;
}
```

Option 1 could look like

```
static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[|]([*_@=])[^|]+\\1[|]");

public static List<Integer> getMatchedIntexes(String s) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()){
        result.add(m.start()+1);//index of character after `|`
        result.add(m.end()-1);  //index of character before `|`
    }

    return result;
}
```

and you could simply use it like

```
String textWithSpecialChars = "text here |*more*| text some other |@tags@|...";

for (int index : getMatchedIntexes(textWithSpecialChars))
    System.out.println(index);
```

which would print

```
11
17
36
42
```

---

Explanation of `[|]([*_@=])[^|]+\\1[|]`

- `[|]` is the same as `\\|` which represent `|` literal
- `([*_@=])` creates group 1 which can contain only `*`, `_`, `@` or `=`
- `[^|]+` will match series of at leas one character which is not `|` (I assume that you don't have any nested `|` inside `|*...*|`. If you do change it to `.*?` which probably will be less efficient
- `\\1` represents match from group 1, so you can find only `|*..*|` sections, not `|*.._|`
- `[|]` as mentioned earlier represents `|` literal.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looking for the start of each pattern match you could just find all of the text that is delimited by special characters like so:

```
public List<String> getSpecialTextList(String line) {
    List<String> toRet = new ArrayList<String>();

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\|([\\*_@=])((?:.(?!\\|))*)\\1\\|");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    while (matcher.find()) {
      toRet.add(matcher.group(2));
    }

    return toRet;
}
```

You can then use it like so:

```
String textWithSpecialChars = "text here |*more*| text some other |@tags@|...";
List<String> specialTextList = getSpecialTextList(textWithSpecialChars);
System.out.println(specialTextList); // prints [more, tags]
```

Note that this will not work for nested tags like `|*hello|*there*|*|`